# Access another implementation files methods and plotting question

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, plot, box2d

In Xcode/cocos2d/box2d I have methods in an .m file called Level1.m, and another in construct.mm. Is it possible to access level1s methods from construct?

Also another question, how would an advanced programmer plot a level with x&y coords beyond the scope of the screen. For example a sidescrolling Mario type game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question.. Look up Inheritance, basic object oriented concept that allows you to utilize and override methods. If you don't want to inherit the class, then simply create an instance of it to use its methods.

As for your second question, I would pretend like the entire screen's coordinates takes up the entire level of your game, but while playing, zoom in (or scale) around the player so that the user can only see what's barely around the character.

Comment: So basically plot everything within 480*320. Once Plotted, zoom In with the cocos2d camera?? Interesting, I never thought of that approach. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Yeah, think of Angry Birds.. everything is already plotted on the screen, and you can zoom in or zoom out with touch. But in your scroll game, plot everything and force it to be scaled up around your character. Glad I could help!

Comment: What if the level is actually quite large, would you use the same approach, I mean angry birds levels in general aren't very big. Not in comparison to say a Mario level..